# Zend_Tool & Zend_Forms inside a module

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-tool

Here's my problem. I'm developping an application using ZF 1.10.0, and I have a module called `Backend`. I need to create a Form for that module. But the damn Zend_Tool won't let me make it inside the `modules/Backend/forms` folder. Is it necessary to put it there (meaning I'll create it manually), ou should I let Zend_Tool create it in the `application/forms` folder ?

Thanks for your help.
Regards from France ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zf create form FormName Backend